# Swapping N variables

Tags: c++, algorithm

There is some function in C ++ that allows to change the value of **N variables** in a circular way?

For example, I have three variables:

```
int i = 5;
int j = 7;
int h = 3;
swap(i,j,h);
// i value is 7
// j value is 3
// h value is 5
```

I could implement using N-1 calls to swap function. But, it can be implemented in a better way, performing fewer operations:

```
int aux = i;
i = j;
j = h;
h = aux;
```

I am interested in N variables (3, 4, 5, 6, ...);

**EDIT:**
Really, I have an int[], and I need to rotate some elements.

```
int a[10] = {1,4,5,3,2,7,8,9,6,0};
```

First, I compute the set of indexes to rotate (for example 2,7,5 and 3), then I need to rotate elements at index 2,7,5 and 3 (values 5, 9, 7, 3), and produce the following change:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9   // indexes
{1,4,5,3,2,7,8,9,6,0}; // values

 0 1 7 2 4 3 6 5 8 9   // moved from index
{1,4,9,5,2,3,8,7,6,0}; // new value
```

Comment: [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) may be what you’re after.

Comment: This is the idea (rotating one position), but applied to variables not to an iterator.

Comment: @JoseMaria put the variables in an array, maybe? then use std::rotate.

Comment: @JoseMaria -- If the variables are this coupled, why are they not in an array to begin with?

Comment: This is not a circular rotation, this is a general permutation. Very different problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I mean it is not a permutation problem. I only need to rotate an arbitrary ordered set of indexes. Really, elements are objects.

Comment: I fail to see a rotation here.

Comment: [I gave it a quick attempt.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53099993defd79a1) I think this works but, like Yves, I’m not sure this is the best approach for mutating a subset of values from a collection.

Comment: This edit is worth another question :)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to simplify the problem, using independent variables, rather than positions of an arrary. That, after all, are non-continuous memory positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `std::rotate` as suggested in the comments.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Container>
void rotate_left(Container& c)
{
    std::rotate(c.begin(), c.begin() + 1, c.end());
}

int main()
{
    int i = 5, j = 7, h = 3;
    std::array<int,3> a {i, j, h};
    std::vector<int> v {i, j, h};
    rotate_left(a);
    rotate_left(v);

    return 0;
}
```

> EDIT: Really, I have an int[], and I need to rotate some elements.

To answer to your second question, you just swap the values:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // input taken from your example
    std::vector<int> v {1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 8, 9, 6, 0};
    std::vector<size_t> indexes {2, 7, 5, 3};

    // swap the values by index (7->2, 5->7, 3->5)
    // note that 2->3 naturally satisfies, hence ind<indexes.size()-1
    for (size_t ind = 0; ind<indexes.size()-1; ++ind)
    {
        std::swap(v[indexes[ind]],v[indexes[ind+1]]);
    }

    return 0;
}
// output: 1, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3, 8, 7, 6, 0
```

This works for arrays (`int[]`) as well of course. Make sure your indexes don't exceed the size of `v`.

**EDIT**

From your comment:

> I am looking for a function that performs the for() {swap} more
>   efficiently

I don't think you'll find something specific in the standard. But maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // input taken from your example
    std::vector<int> v {1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 8, 9, 6, 0};
    std::vector<size_t> indexes {2, 7, 5, 3};

    // rotate the values by index (7->2, 5->7, 3->5, 2->3)
    int tmp = v[indexes[0]];
    for (size_t ind = 0; ind<indexes.size()-1; ++ind)
        v[indexes[ind]] = v[indexes[ind+1]];
    v[indexes.back()] = tmp;        

    return 0;
}
// output: 1, 4, 9, 5, 2, 3, 8, 7, 6, 0
```

[Here](http://quick-bench.com/KnHWgbrc3JOhkjtqLQnPiEZWbG8) is a benchmark you can play with.

Comment: But rotate funtion rotates all the elements, I only need to rotate an arbitrary ordered set of them.

Comment: @JoseMaria what is an arbitrary ordered set? `std::rotate` does not rotate **all** elements, only those in the range you ask it for

Comment: For example, I need to rotate elements at index (4, 10, 5, 6 and 0). This is an arbitrary ordered set, not is the same to rotate (10, 6, 5, 0, 4).

Comment: I edited the answer. It now reproduces your example correctly,

Comment: I will open a new question. I am looking for a function that performs the for() {swap} more efficiently. Do the swap of N variables.

Comment: @JoseMaria Not sure you can do it faster. The compiler can optimize this heavily. It's probably all done in CPU registers. If you try some trick without temp variable when swapping, you'll probably have worse results.

Comment: @JoseMaria I got curious and added an example with only 1 temp variable. With gcc9.1 there is almost no performance difference. With clang 8.0 the difference is more significant.

Comment: @Mfnx So, the right answer is: you don't need it. Performing in a loop is so optimal as the function required. Many thanks!